# Как использовать Mobile SDK VK API?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, phaser-framework

Прошу помочь разобраться с темой использования VK API в Direct Games вконтакте.
Есть прототип игры и хотел разобраться с работой api.

Суть вопроса- как правильно делать запрос `users.get` чтобы я мог вывести на экран игры имя пользователя который в данный момент играет в игру, я писал вот так:

```
VK.init(function(){
    VK.api('users.get',{ user_ids:1,fields:"photo_big"},function(data){});
  },
  function(){},'5.60');
};
```

Подскажите что не правильно ?
Огромное спасибо заранее!!

Comment: У вас в коде 2 последних символа скорее лишние, или вы забыли код предшествующий этому.

Comment: Сейчас актуальная версия 5.80

Answer (score 0):

Пользователи - массив:

VK.api('users.get', {user_ids:[1],fields:"photo_big"}, function(data){});

если приложение в тесте, то добавить в словарь параметров:

test_mode: 1